# Cassandra: How to model column family to perform intersect-like queries

Tags: database-design, cassandra, intersect, cql3

Basically I have three attributes: `partId`, `measurementDef` and `value`.
Each part (partId) consists of multiple measures (value) of a certain type (measurementDef).

Formatted as a tree it would look something like this:

```
-part 1
  |- measurementDef 1 -> 15,86
  |- measurementDef 2 -> 19,54
-part 2
  |- measurementDef 1 -> 21,21
  |- measurementDef 3 -> 65,54
  |- measurementDef 4 -> 12,54
-part 3
   ...
```

Now my question is: How should I model my column family to do something like this:

```
SELECT partId
FROM <table>
WHERE measurementDef = xxx AND value > 10
INTERSECT
SELECT partId
FROM <table>
WHERE measurementDef = yyy AND value < 50
```

In other words: I want to find all parts, whose value for measurementDef xxx is higher 10 and whose value for measurementDef yyy is lower 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no modelling approach to make intersection within single query. I suggest to use following table design:

```
create table mdefparts(
    mdef int,
    value float,
    parts set<uuid>,
    primary key(mdef, value)
);
```

Then use queries:

```
select parts from mdefparts where mdef=XXX and value > 10;
select parts from mdefparts where mdef=YYY and value < 50;
```

Then join all sets from the first query into one set (say, set1).

Join all sets from the second query into set2.

Then just intersect set1 and set2.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an alternative.

You could create a "dummy" column that are set to one or zero during insertion if a threshold is exceed. Then, create a composite column index like so:

```
    CREATE TABLE mdefparts (
            part int,
            name text,
            val double,
            time timeuuid,
            exceeded boolean,
            PRIMARY KEY ((part, name), exceeded, time)
    );
```

This would work like so:

```
    cqlsh:test> CREATE TABLE mdefparts (
            ... part int,
            ... name text,
            ... val double,
            ... time timeuuid,
            ... exceeded boolean,
            ... PRIMARY KEY ((part, name), exceeded, time)
            ... );
    cqlsh:test> 
    cqlsh:test> insert into mdefparts (part, name, val, time, exceeded) values (0, 'y', 100, 37a5de5c-efb3-11e2-99d0-f23c91aec05e, true);
    cqlsh:test> insert into mdefparts (part, name, val, time, exceeded) values (0, 'x', 100, 37a5de6c-efb3-11e2-99d0-f23c91aec05e, true);
    cqlsh:test> insert into mdefparts (part, name, val, time, exceeded) values (0, 'y', 10, 37a5de7c-efb3-11e2-99d0-f23c91aec05e, false);
    cqlsh:test> insert into mdefparts (part, name, val, time, exceeded) values (1, 'y', 1, 37a5de8c-efb3-11e2-99d0-f23c91aec05e, false);
    cqlsh:test> select * from mdefparts;

     part | name | exceeded | time                                 | val
    ------+------+----------+--------------------------------------+-----
        0 |    y |    False | 37a5de7c-efb3-11e2-99d0-f23c91aec05e |  10
        0 |    y |     True | 37a5de5c-efb3-11e2-99d0-f23c91aec05e | 100
        1 |    y |    False | 37a5de8c-efb3-11e2-99d0-f23c91aec05e |   1
        0 |    x |     True | 37a5de6c-efb3-11e2-99d0-f23c91aec05e | 100

    cqlsh:test> select * from mdefparts where name in ('x','y') and part = 0 and exceeded = true;

     part | name | exceeded | time                                 | val
    ------+------+----------+--------------------------------------+-----
        0 |    x |     True | 37a5de6c-efb3-11e2-99d0-f23c91aec05e | 100
        0 |    y |     True | 37a5de5c-efb3-11e2-99d0-f23c91aec05e | 100
```

The core idea here was here to model the query into the column family. I added a timeuuid to allow multiple measurements over time.

Comment: Interesting solution, but this requires to know the threshold up front.

Comment: It would need to be defined in your application, yes. 
You can improve on this by adding to "exceeded" an integer column that denotes value ranges recorded in val. For instance:
0: 0-19
1: 20-99
2: 100-199
3: 200-499
This would be more fine grained and you could detect certain ranges of values you are interested in more easily. Just add a secondary index on this column. Hope that helps!